# Target specific db engine version while generating migration script in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, mariadb

While deploying my application using MariaDb, I generate migration script with dotnet ef:

```
dotnet ef migrations script --output script.sql
```

The script generated is compliant with the database engine used for development, in my case mariadb 10.6.12.

But my production server use 10.3 and in my migration script, I rename a column and the syntaxt had changed at version 10.5. There fore, the script fail on the rename.

So, is it possible to generate a migration script targeting a specific db engine, in my case 10.3?

Information: I cannot generate the script connected to my production server since I deploy all the infrastructure using Terraform and apply the migration script on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to generate the migration script targeting a specific MariaDb version : run it in in Docker.

Prepare your application by edit the default connection in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=MySchema;Uid=MyUser;Pwd=password;"
```

Use the following Powershell script to generate the script. Make sure that the credentials are the same as in your appsettings.json

```
# Version of MariaDb to instanciate
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$EngineVersion
)

#Pull and launch a mariadb container in targeted version image
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -p 3306:3306 -d --name dummymaria mariadb:$EngineVersion
# Wait 10s in order MariaDb is up and running
Write-Host "Wait 10s MariaDb instance had started..."
Start-Sleep 10

# Create the schema 
docker exec -it --env MYSQL_PWD=mypass dummymaria mysql -u root -v -e "CREATE SCHEMA MySchema;"
# Create a user (use the same user as in you appsettings.json and same password)
docker exec -it --env MYSQL_PWD=mypass dummymaria mysql -u root -v -e "CREATE USER 'MyUser'@'%' identified by 'password';"
# grant all privileges for any hosts
docker exec -it --env MYSQL_PWD=mypass dummymaria mysql -u root -v -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on MySchema.* to'MyUser'@'%';"
# flush privileges
docker exec -it --env MYSQL_PWD=mypass dummymaria mysql -u root -v -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

# generate the migration script. The tool will connect to the container
dotnet ef migrations script --output script-$EngineVersion.sql  --idempotent

# Destroy the container
docker rm dummymaria --force
```

The script generated (`script-10.3.sql`) should be compliant with the targeted database.